# NestJS: How to access both Body and Param in custom validator?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, validation, nestjs

I've a scenario where I need values from both values in the *param* and *body* to perform custom validation. For example, I've a route `/:photoId/tag` that adds a tag to a photo.

However, before it can add a tag to a photo, it has to validate whether there is already an existing tag of the same name with the photo.

I have the following route in my controller:

```
@Post(':photoId/tag')
@UsePipes(new ValidationPipe())
async addTag(
    @Param() params: AddTagParams,
    @Body() addTagDto: AddTagDto
) {
    // ...
}
```

Since the `:photoId` is provided as a *param* and the `tag` is provided in the *body* of the request, they can't access each other in the custom validator and I can't use both pieces of information to do a check against the database:

```
export class IsPhotoTagExistValidator implements ValidatorConstraintInterface {

    async validate(val: any, args: ValidationArguments) {
        // supposed to check whether a tag of the same name already exists on photo
        // val only has the value of photoId but not the name of the tag from AddTagDto in Body
    }
}   


export class AddTagParams{
   @IsInt()
   @Validate(IsPhotoTagExistValidator)   // this doesn't work because IsPhotoTagExistValidator can't access tag in AddTagDto
   photoId: number
}

export class AddTagDto{
   @IsString()
   tag: string
}
```

As in the example above, the `val` in `IsPhotoTagExistValidator` is only the `photoId`. But I need both the `photoId` in Param and `tag` name in the Body to check whether the particular `photoId` already has that `tag`.

How should I access both the Body and Param in the custom validator function? If not, how should I approach this problem?

Comment: I'd use pipes only for the validation of the form (type, length etc.) of the requests but not for the validation of business requirements (image tags must be unique), especially when the database is involved. In my opinion, this should be part of the corresponding service. (Of course it's unclear where to draw the line.)

Comment: @KimKern I think you got a point. One of the reason I thought I would use a validator for unique image tags instead of implementing it in the service is because when throwing an exception from the service, the error response is very different from the error response from what the class-validation provides. So I thought if I had the validation done as a validator, I would get similar error details in the error response.

Comment: I added a solution for graphQL [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75938042/10375590). I hope I could help you!

Answer (score 7):

The only solution I have found so far was derived from this comment https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/528#issuecomment-497020970

`context.interceptor.ts`

```
import { CallHandler, ExecutionContext, Injectable, NestInterceptor } from '@nestjs/common'
import { Observable } from 'rxjs'

/**
 * Injects request data into the context, so that the ValidationPipe can use it.
 */
@Injectable()
export class ContextInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
  intercept(
    context: ExecutionContext,
    next: CallHandler
  ): Observable<any> {
    const request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();

    request.body.context = {
      params: request.params,
      query: request.query,
      user: request.user,
    };

    return next.handle()
  }
}
```

`main.ts`

```
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  app.useGlobalInterceptors(new ContextInterceptor());
  // ...
}
```

If you use `{whitelist: true}` in `ValidationPipe` params you will need to allow `context` in your Dto objects.

this can be done by extending such Dto:

`context-aware.dto.ts`

```
import { Allow } from 'class-validator';

export class ContextAwareDto {
  @Allow()
  context?: {
    params: any,
    query: any,
    user: any,
  }
}
```

After this, you will be able to access request data when validating body in custom validator via `validationArguments.object.context`

You can easily adjust the above to access the context when validating params or query, although I find it sufficient to have this only during body validation.

Comment: This works just right except for the interceptors implementation that did not worked for me. I followed the documentation https://docs.nestjs.com/interceptors

Comment: well, it works. Unless you provide some more details in terms of what exactly did not work, it's hard to assist.