# Access context in NestJS custom validator (GraphQL)

Tags: nestjs, class-validator

I'm trying to write a custom validator. The thing is that my validation depends on an attribute of the user that is making the request. I'm using passport so the user is attached to the context and in every request I have the following decorator (please note I'm using GraphQL)

```
export const CurrentUser = createParamDecorator(
  (_data: unknown, context: ExecutionContext) => {
    if (context.getType() === 'http') {
      return context.switchToHttp().getRequest().user;
    }

    const ctx = GqlExecutionContext.create(context);
    return ctx.getContext().req.user;
  },
);
```

I was wondering if there is anyway in which I can access the user inside the validate function of the custom validator.
I tried the solution in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55481224/nestjs-how-to-access-both-body-and-param-in-custom-validator) but I'm not being able to make it work for graphql. I don't know where should I add the user info in the context so that it is available in the validationArguments parameter of the validate function (of the ValidatorConstraintInterface).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem as you, as I also use graphQL.  The approach described [here](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/528#issuecomment-497020970) is actually only useful for REST requests and not for graphQL. But after a longer research I found the following point in the documentation of [NestJS](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/execution-context#host-handler-arguments).

So if you don't change the body but the input, it might work, I thought, and indeed it does. This means that you can follow the complete [instructions](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/528#issuecomment-497020970) and only have to pay attention to this point in the Interceptor.

```
@Injectable()
export class ContextInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
  intercept(
    context: ExecutionContext,
    next: CallHandler
  ): Observable<any> {
    const ctx = GqlExecutionContext.create(context);

    const args = ctx.getArgs();

    if (args.input) {
      args.input = {
        context: {
          user: req.user
        },
        ...args.input
      };
    }

    return next.handle();
  }
}
```

**And the result is**

```
{
  targetName: 'UpdateUserInput',
  property: 'role',
  object: UpdateUserInput {
    context: { user: [UserEntity] },
    role: 'Moderator'
  },
  value: 'Moderator',
  constraints: undefined
}
```

I hope I could help you